# Wrapfig near Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, wrapfig

Why does the wrapfig appear to be longer than the contents? Is there a better way to wrap text, including a ToC, around a figure?

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{2.5in}
    \rule{2.5in}{2.5in}
\end{wrapfigure}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{1.5in}
    \tableofcontents{}
    \end{minipage}}

\section{One}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Two}
\lipsum[3][1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image: Weird wrapfig spacing error]

Answer (score 2):

`wrapfigure` environments are often way too long, but you can specify the number of lines the `wrapfigure` should span vertically as a first optional argument.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[10]{L}{2.5in}
    \rule{2.5in}{2.5in}
\end{wrapfigure}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{1.5in}
    \tableofcontents{}
    \end{minipage}}

\section{One}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Two}
\lipsum[3][1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like my wrapfigure is too long, by the height of the table of contents, like the size of the black box is being taken out of every paragraph it touches instead of only as much as necessary being taken out. The original document is in LyX, but I was hoping to figure out a simpler way of making it work properly. I guess I can do wrapfig with ERT.

Comment: Yes, but it does not work if you specify the height of the wrapfigure in the optional argument, like I described? It should make the wrapfigure less long.

Comment: As to "why"... The boxed TOC counts as one line, and the large section title counts as one line, but the number of lines to wrap is calculated based on ordinary text.